# Find UserControl in Form when Added

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I write code to add UserControl in Form:

```
        UserControl edt = new UserControl();
        edt.Name = "ItemEdit";
        frm_Editor frm = new frm_Editor();
        frm.Controls.Add(edt);
        frm.Show();
```

And then, I find UserControl in Form:

```
Control[] tbxs = this.Controls.Find("ItemEdit", true);
if (tbxs != null && tbxs.Length > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Found");
}
```

But the result is null && tbxs.Length = 0
Please guide me solutions to process problems. Thanks so much!

Comment: Is it `wpf` or `winform`?

Comment: Every time somebody tries to use WPF without MVVM, God makes a kitten waste two days on a trivial task that should take ten minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It works in this small program, and it might point you towards a solution with your own code.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FormTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Form1 frm = new Form1();
            UserControl edt = new UserControl();
            edt.Name = "ItemEdit";
            frm.Controls.Add(edt);

            Application.Run(frm);
        }
    }
}

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FormTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Control[] tbxs = this.Controls.Find("ItemEdit", true);
            if (tbxs != null && tbxs.Length > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```